# Stopping an active mq route without logging as error

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We have an activemq topic set with several possible routes when a file is received on the server (for example).

Currently the routes all have some form of sanitisation that check if they should even attempt to process the file.  The sanitisation is throwing a custom process exception, this is the only way (so far) that I can see to stop a message being passed down the process, if the output would be of no value.

However; this is being logged as an error, when I only really want it showing as a warning or info.

I am currently looking to see if log4j can be set to log that type of error at a lesser severity, or how I might  extend the processor class with a custom class.

**update**
Currently looking at this on the camel apache site: http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html

Comment: You can tweak the logging level and whether stacktraces in logged and whatnot on the Camel error handler.

Comment: Thanks Claus, in our investigations it does look like you can downgrade the error, but that felt a bit of a cheat, so we are looking at the architecture and using concurrency to move the data sanitation to a collection of processes. Once we have worked it all out, I will post a response.